# Unity Mesh Collider

Tags: unity-game-engine

I got wrong colliders with Mesh Collider, I used Blender to create model. How can I fix them?

[image]

Settings

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just uncheck **Convex** but in this case it wouldn't work well with physical collisions.

if you need non Convex colliders and working physics at the same time you should buy something like this [asset store link](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/physics/non-convex-mesh-collider-84867)

Or you can use this script [github link](https://github.com/bahadir147/TransporterSim/blob/52e54d79a3c7c7edafa1e2d6083221353f042b86/Assets/_Assets/Scripts/Utility/NonConvexMeshCollider.cs) for free

Comment: when I uncheck it, my objects fall through the floor

Comment: Unity's physics can't work with non convex colliders

Comment: meanwhile, you can try to use this script [github link](https://github.com/bahadir147/TransporterSim/blob/52e54d79a3c7c7edafa1e2d6083221353f042b86/Assets/_Assets/Scripts/Utility/NonConvexMeshCollider.cs)

Comment: I updated the original answer. Now it also contains a link from the comments.

Comment: Also note that you should avoid any transformations of a mesh collider (moving, rotating, scaling) as it requires Unity to re-compute the underlying math, which is relatively slow.

Comment: The script you shared as free is not free anymore, remove it. https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/physics/non-convex-mesh-collider-84867#content